# Didn't Trystane Martell leave?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Warning: SPOILERS for the first episode of season six (and the end of season five):

> How could prince Trystane Martell be killed by the Sandsnakes? Wasn't he supposed to be on the ship with Jaime and Myrcella? At some point in the last episode of season 5, the sandsnakes can be seen ashore. We can only assume that Trystane stays and later takes one of his own ships. But why would he do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timeline of the events is different from how it is portrayed in the show, as speculated in [this answer on the Movies SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/52240/13595):

> **Prince Trystane was assassinated while on a ship that was docked at
>   King's Landing several weeks after the assassination of Prince Doran.**
>
> The episode doesn't really make this clear, because events in Game of
>   Thrones can be quite apart in time, despite being shown in a linear
>   fashion.
>
> The events in Dorne do appear to happen
>   directly after the last episode of Season 5.
>   However since Prince Trystane was on a ship that went to King's
>   Landing, some time must have passed.
>   How much time? I'm no sailor but the distance between the two looks
>   quite big and I would guess at least several weeks.
>
> Presumably Obara and Nymeria Sand also sailed to King's Landing just
>   behind Trystane Martell.
>
> **Things are being shown happening at very different times.**

Trystane remaining on the ship is most likely caused by the possibility of retaliation from the Lannisters.

Of interest is Jaime Lannister's letter to Prince Doran Martell, which is [available on the Making Game of Thrones website](http://www.makinggameofthrones.com/production-diary/objects-from-dorne):

[image: Jaime's letter to Prince Doran Martell]

He writes:

> [...] Your son cannot stay in King's Landing [...] am sending him back
>   on the same ship.

Comment: I think the question #TheFrozenOne was asking was why was Trystane left alone on the ship instead of going ashore with Jaime and Myrcella. If he'd been with them then he couldn't have been killed by SandSnakes.

Comment: More of a two part question, but you're right, the second part was about why he didn't leave with Jaime and Myrcella.

Comment: That makes no sense. The journey would surely last days, somebody would find his dead body really quickly. With two dead young nobles, you'd think they'd turn the ship around immediatly and go to Doran (especially since his son is dead). The entire Dorne plot makes me tear my hair out... "we don't kill young girls in Dorne"... but appereantly 100 yards off shore everything is fair game.

Comment: "We don't kiill young girls in Dorne" was said by Doran. Obviously Ellaria and the Sandsnakes didn't aggree with that.

Comment: @TheFrozenOne shhh!!!......don't say it was a two part question, else it will get downvoted.....lol

Answer (score 1):

Season 6 Eps 1 showed that the Sandsnakes's Sea Ship carrying Tristane,Jaime and Myrcella's dead body have reached King's Landing. They didnt enter through the shipping docks but instead some shore near the castle hence they had to anchor a far and use a boat to come ashore. No one(except those who boarding the ship) knows that Tristane is aboard the ship which could the reason why they didnt enter through the dock. I would assume Jaime left Tristane on the ship knowing that Cersei would want Tristane to be executed to avenge Myrcella's death.

The question asks 3 questions

1. `How could prince Trystane Martell be killed by the Sandsnakes?`
   It seems that all the sandsnakes people was in on the assasination of the Martells. It would seem that the two sisters later caught up and sneaked in to assasinate Trystane.
2. `Wasn't he supposed to be on the ship with Jaime and Myrcella?`
   Yes he was on the ship with Jaime and Myrcella.
3. `The sandsnakes can be seen ashore while we can only assume that Trystane stays and later takes one of his own ships. But why would he do so?`
   answered already above.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any way.

Comment: The first two question, wasn't even a question. The main question was why was tristane left on the ship

Answer (score 1):

In our world gambling is illegal in a state or city but the same law doesn't apply on a boat outside jurisdiction on the water. I propose that Myrcella died in "international waters", not in Dorne. Although, the act was committed on a dock on the shores of the kingdom.

The time period isn't well explained, neither is where the killing of Trystane happens.

I would also  say maybe the show runners gave us the letter from Jaime to assume that he sent Trystane back to Dorne. (previously mentioned) The ship was intercepted entering Dorne coming back to port? But, if that was the case why would he be painting the eye for Myrcella? So I guess the reality of the situation is that Jaime did plan to send Trystane back to Dorne on the same ship on which they arrived, but the Sand Snakes - yes they split up and committed the murder of Trystane off-shore of Kings Landing. While simultaneously the remaining women kill Doran, and his crew.

The Sand Snakes responsible for the murder of Trystane were allowed time to arrive leaving shortly after Jaime. While the other two remaining women carefully wait for the arrival of news of Myrcella. Which would take a while to make it's way back to Dorne in the first place. Right?